# Unable to run Python CGI Script using IIS on Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, iis-7

Tried to configure IIS 7 on Windows 10 to run Python CGI Script. My Python version is 3.7.3. I followed the following tutorial [Running Python CGI Scripts on IIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7whncKjSXK0&t=216s)

I followed all of the instructions exactly but now I am getting this error 
[HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN0Kv.jpg)

Someone please help.  I have spent hours behind this.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you may not add the cgi handler well.

I suggest you could try to follow below steps to add the python cgi.

1. Install the IIS CGI feature:
   You could open the control panel's Programs and Features and enable the IIS's CGI

[image]

2. Open the IIS management console and click the handler mapping feature

[image]

3. Add below setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Python 3.7.3 is supported.